# Login form script change after introducing username and password

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have this form:

```
<div class="page3">
              <form id="indexform" action="index.php" method="post">
              <table class="datatable2"  style="padding:20;" >
              <tr>

                  <td><center>Username  </center><input type="text" name="name" value="" size="10" /></td>

              </tr>
              <tr>

                  <td><center>Password </center><input type="password" name="password" value="" size="10" /></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
               <td colspan="2" class="datatable2" style="padding:55 0 0 38;">
                      <input type="submit" value="Log In" name="admsubmit" class="subbtn" style="background-image: url(imagini/autentificare.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:10 5;background-size:17px;"/></form>

                  </td>
                  <tr>
                  <td colspan="2" class="datatable2" style="padding:40 0 0 8;">
                      <form action="parola_uitata.php"> <input type="submit" align="right" value="Ai uitat parola?" class="subbtn" style="background-image: url(imagini/parola_uitata.png);background-position:11;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:17px;margin:-45 1;padding-left:30;" name="parola_uitata"></form>

                  </td>
              </tr>
</table>

             </div>
```

IMAGE:

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dvWP.png]

and i want to know how i can hide after logging, and only displaying in same div some like : Hello `($_SESSION['user'])` -- go to admin panel. If someone can give me some idea it would be helpful me.

Comment: suggestion: try avoid submitting forms to the index pages.

Comment: What have you tried yourself? A quick hint would be to do a `if($logged_in){}`

Comment: Why to avoid  submitting forms to the index pages ?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap an if statement around your markup, and display based on the state of the session (if they are logged in or not)

```
<div class="page3">
    <?php if(!isset($_SESSION['logged_in'])) : ?>
         <form id="indexform" action="index.php" method="post">
          <table class="datatable2"  style="padding:20;" >
             <tr>
                <td><center>Username</center><input type="text" name="name" value="" size="10" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><center>Password </center><input type="password" name="password" value="" size="10" /></td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
               <td colspan="2" class="datatable2" style="padding:55 0 0 38;">
                          <input type="submit" value="Log In" name="admsubmit" class="subbtn" style="background-image: url(imagini/autentificare.png);background-repeat:no-repeat;background-position:10 5;background-size:17px;"/></form>

                      </td>
                      <tr>
                      <td colspan="2" class="datatable2" style="padding:40 0 0 8;">
                          <form action="parola_uitata.php"> <input type="submit" align="right" value="Ai uitat parola?" class="subbtn" style="background-image: url(imagini/parola_uitata.png);background-position:11;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-size:17px;margin:-45 1;padding-left:30;" name="parola_uitata">
                   </form>
               </td>
          </tr>
    </table>
    <?php else : ?>

    <-- User logged in, show control panel stuff !-->

    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks, but how to do if i have 3 tipes of users in 3 different tables?

Comment: Set a session variable containing the user type, and then add extra "if" conditions based on the user type when outputting the result of the login action.